# Run sql script result as job in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know if there is any way to execute a task in SQL that executes the result of a query

these is my script:

```
SELECT serie,noDoctoFiscal,total,shipperid,fechaemision,
  'update xDoctoFiscalDigital set PDFpath =''C:\Webfact Files Pdfs\Facturas\'
  + RTRIM(noDoctoFiscal) 
  + '_' + RTRIM(ShipperId) +'.pdf'''
  + ' ' 
  + 'where shipperid = ''' +rtrim([ShipperId])+ ''' 'as 'Path'
from xDoctoFiscalDigital 
WHERE fechaemision > ='2018-12-01' and serie ='TEC'
and PDFpath is null
order by fechaemision desc
```

and this is the result of my first script:

```
update xDoctoFiscalDigital set PDFpath ='C:\Webfact Files Pdfs\Facturas\TEC73535_0EPV085629.pdf' where shipperid = '0EPV085629'
```

I need to make a job that execute the script result.
Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Output the results as text in SSMS and cut and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem thanks to forum support https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/
This is the solution to the problem presented:

I hope it helps somebody else

```
DECLARE @SQString NVARCHAR(1000) = '' 

SELECT
@SQString = N'update xDoctoFiscalDigital set PDFpath =''C:\Webfact Files Pdfs\Facturas\'+RTRIM(noDoctoFiscal)  + '_' +
 RTRIM(ShipperId) + '.pdf''' + ' ' + 'where shipperid = ''' + rtrim(ShipperId) + ''' ' 
FROM
   xDoctoFiscalDigital 
WHERE
   fechaemision > = '2018-12-01' 
   AND serie = 'TEC'
   AND PDFpath IS NULL 
ORDER BY
   fechaemision DESC EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQString
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for your scenario:

Create a table "COMMANDS" to bulk the data from the select statement , and add a field to let you know if that row has been proccesed.

Once you have data on "COMMANDS" , you can create a procedure that exec all the statements 
that still un-proccesed.

You can make it with a loop or a cursor or CTE ...

Good luck.

Comment: but how can i do that? i am new in SQL
thanks

Comment: I have done the entire code but dont know hot to insert it in this response.it has 66 lines of code one script but cant paste it says too many characters. any idea how to do it without post 3 or 4 answers ?